# Go - LDFLAGS: -w -hostobj gives error

Tags: linker, go, cgo

I am writing a Go package that calls C code. I need to invoke the host linker, but unfortunately adding the `-hostobj` flag gives me following error:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-h’
```

Operating system is Linux, architecture amd64.

Here are all the flags:

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I. -fPIC
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lstdc++ -w -hostobj -L. libsomething.a
// #include "something.h"
// #include <stdlib.h>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is that `-hostobj` flag supposed to do? I don't find it in either the gcc or ld manual pages. (And `-w` looks strange.)

Comment: I'm not sure if I got that right, but from what I understood it tells the Go linker to use the host's linker. http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4069

Answer (score 1):

At `tip` of Go source repository `default` branch, use `-linkmode`, not `-hostobj`. For example, `-linkmode=external`.

[Issue 4069](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4069)`: cmd/ld: invoke host linker for cgo build` has not been marked as fixed.

Comment: I'm using a build from hg (revision +1405be4b6fc4). Adding that to LDFLAGS gives me `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -linkmode=external`. If I do `go install -ldflags "-linkmode=external"` it compiles, but I think it's getting ignored because it does not complain with `-hostobj` either.. And I'm still getting linking errors I wanted to avoid. How can I validate that the flag is being used?